# How can I create A Class with Trait On Scala?

Tags: class, scala, generics, traits

Trait GenericLinkedList , case class Cons and case object Nil were created like below.
The question is I want to use this genericLinkedList however as you know when we write this code `var list = new GenericLinkedList` , it will not cause Traits cannot create any object , Right? I want to create a class which extends GenericLinkedList but I cannot. How can I fix it ?

```
trait GenericLinkedList [+T] {
def prepend[TT >: T](x: TT): GenericLinkedList[TT] = this match {
    case _ => Cons(x,this) 
  }
}
case class Cons[+T](head: T,tail: GenericLinkedList[T]) extends GenericLinkedList[T]
case object Nil extends GenericLinkedList[Nothing]
```

Comment: Now, The trait GenericLinkedList just do prepend method , Am I right ?The Question is How can I use these method another class or another project ? For Instance I want to use these GenericLinkedList to store any thing on another place. I did search somewhere it possible with **extends** . However when I did create something like that **class list[+T] extends GenericLinkedList[T]** it will not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be unable of doing

```
val list = new GenericLinkedList
```

Is your goal creating an empty list?

You can do

```
val list = new GenericLinkedList[Int] { }
```

since the trait is not abstract, but it's not pretty. You can alternatively define a companion object for your trait

```
object GenericLinkedList {
  def apply[T](): GenericLinkedList[T] = Nil
}
```

and use it to initialize an empty list this way

```
scala> val x = GenericLinkedList[Int]()
// x: GenericLinkedList[Int] = Nil

scala> x.prepend(42)
// res0: GenericLinkedList[Int] = Cons(42,Nil)
```

---

By the way, the universal `match` in the `prepend` implementation is useless. You can just do

```
 def prepend[TT >: T](x: TT): GenericLinkedList[TT] = Cons(x, this)
```

Comment: Yes, my goal is creating a new LinkedList which has type what I want (Int,String,Any..etc). As you know generic code is very strong to Use it. Unfortunately , when I did try your answer with defining a companion object for my trait , I still get error message like that : **trait GenericLinkedList is abstract; cannot be instantiated
       var list = new GenericLinkedList[Int]()**

Comment: `{}` not `()`, but you should really prefer the definition of a companion object.

Comment: Thank you Gabrielle again , I did fix it with var list = new GenericLinkedList[Int]{} , now I can create linkedlist which include different types. I think you should edit your code part **var list = new GenericLinkedList[Int]()** with **var list = new GenericLinkedList[Int]{}** because somebody who reads your code to do not make any mistake :) By the way, Is there any source which fix  this issue , you can share with link or something else.And, I was studying with pattern matching and thats why I use it on prepend thanks for your attention.